# Bazel build Android demo fail with Proguard

Tags: android, bazel, kotlin-coroutines

Can't build an Android demo with Bazel when proguard_specs is enable.

Error log:

```
...
Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowMerge$collectTo$$inlined$collect$1$lambda$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object emit$$forInline(java.lang.Object,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowMerge$collectTo$$inlined$collect$1
Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object emit$$forInline(java.lang.Object,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1
Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1$lambda$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object emit$$forInline(java.lang.Object,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1
Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.CombineKt$zipImpl$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1$lambda$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.CombineKt$zipImpl$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1
Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.FlowCoroutineKt$scopedFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1$lambda$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.FlowCoroutineKt$scopedFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 51 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
ProGuard, version 5.3.3
...
Note: kotlinx.coroutines.CommonPool accesses a method 'getPoolSize()' dynamically
      Maybe this is library method 'java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool { int getPoolSize(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor { int getPoolSize(); }'
Note: there were 5 classes trying to access annotations using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the annotation attributes
      (using '-keepattributes *Annotation*').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 4 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 2 classes trying to access enclosing methods using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the enclosing method attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 15 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 29 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
Target //app/src/main:app failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 3.238s, Critical Path: 3.10s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Bazel config:

```
android_binary(
    name = "app",
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    custom_package = "felix.duan.androidnavisample",
    manifest_values = {
        "minSdkVersion": "21",
        "versionCode" : "2",
        "versionName" : "2.0",
        "targetSdkVersion" : "29",
    },
    proguard_generate_mapping = True,
    proguard_specs = ["proguard-rules.pro"],
    deps = [
        ":lib",
    ]
)
```

proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep class org.jetbrains.annotations.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
```

Build tools:

```
bazel: v3.7.0-homebrew
rules_kotlin_version: legacy-1.4.0-rc4
android sdk: v30.0.2
```

**Question A: How to solve this problem?**

addition questions I found related to this:

**Question B: Does Bazel consume transitive dependency proguard?** If not, this could be the cause?

**Question C: Does Bazel support R8?** I found no direct info to this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only a warning, maybe you can disable it in the proguard config:

```
 -dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.**
```

And then error which is **Error: Please correct the above warnings first.** might go away.